# Группировка выпадающего списка

Tags: html, список

Добрый день! На сайте есть выпадающий список с выбором категорий и подкатегорий. Необходимо сделать корневые категории, чтобы они пользователями не выбирались а были просто видны, а пользователи выбирали только подкатегории. Поизучав HTML пришел к выводу вводить теги optgroup. Но как его прописать при таком коде?

```
<select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="text-input" style="width:407px" onchange="getRubric();"><option value="0">-- {$LANG.SELECT_CAT} --</option>
        {$catslist}
                </select>
            </td>
```

Comment: Здесь, судя по всему, в переменной $catlist содерится уже весь список целиком, надо смотреть, как он формируется.

Comment: Нашел такие строчки.
// Получаем категории, в которые может загружать пользователь
 $catslist = $model->getPublicCats($model->category_id);
 if(!$catslist) {
  cmsCore::addSessionMessage($_LANG['YOU_CANT_ADD_ADV_ANY'], 'error');
  $inCore->redirect('/board');

Comment: А если допустим убрать переменную и прописать постоянные значения с тегами optgroup